# Como configurar a sessão do Codeigniter correta na versão atual do mesmo?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Bom, para ser mais específico, o meu problema com as sessões do Codeigniter começou a ocorrer após eu trocar meu Xampp para uma versão mais atual (v.7...). Em se tratando de código/projeto eu não fiz se quer alguma alteração, o que poderia ser?

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: O Xampp em si não interfere na versão, o Xampp é um pacote de programas, o que você tem que informar é a versão do PHP e a versão do Codeigniter que esta usando, também informe as configurações de session do PHP.INI.

Comment: Exatamente @GuilhermeNascimento, assim como o EASYPHP (que particularmente prefiro), por isso questionei qual é o erro apresentado.

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: Ai pessoal já consegui resolver, o que fiz? Atualizei meu Codeigniter... Valeu!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ai pessoal já consegui resolver, o que fiz? Atualizei meu Codeigniter... Valeu!